# A question in 1st uniqueness theorem of primary decomposition

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, primary-decomposition

I am self studying commutative algebra from a class notes  based on atiyah and macdonald and I am struck on this proof.

> Statement; Let $I=\cap_{i=1}^n q_i$ be a minimal primary decomposition of I. Then $\sqrt{q_i}=p_i's $ are precisely the prime ideals in $S=${$ \sqrt{I:x} : x\in A$}

Proof:  If $\sqrt{I:x } =p$ is a prime ideal $=> \sqrt{\cap_{i=1}^n q_i :x} =p= \sqrt{ \cap_{i=1}^n (q_i:x)} =\cap_{i=1}^n \sqrt{ q_i:x}= \cap_{ x\notin q_i}p_i$.

I am not able to understand the last step how author wrote $\cap_{i=1}^n \sqrt{ q_i:x}= \cap_{ x\notin q_i}p_i$.

Can you please help me prove this assertion?

Comment: Open AM textbook and read the lemma before the theorem you mentioned here.

Comment: @user26857 will have a look. thanks!

Comment: @user26857 Can you please tell on which page of book it is? I looked twice but couldn't find it.